# How to get getEnabled callback method to run in VB.net Ribbon project

Tags: excel, ribbon

I have this XML code for a Ribbon button

```
<button id="Button9" label="Cover Index" image="cover"
                size="large" onAction="Viewcover" getEnabled="GetBEnabled" />
```

I'm using Visual Studio and inserted this getEnabled callback method in the callback Region as instructed

```
Public Sub GetBEnabled(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl, ByVal returnedVal As Boolean)

    returnedVal = True

End Sub
```

Although returnedVal is set to True, still the button is not enabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the right syntax for getEnabled callback method in VB.net is:

```
Function GetBEnabled(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl) As Boolean

    Return True

End Function
```

Thanks